# Creating a small database using variables for constructor names

Tags: java

I am trying to create an application that will let you

1 - add  people to a small database

2 - append their name onto an array

3 - when retrieving information previously entered, the array will be used to select the person

4 - retrieve unique information of the person selected

I have two classes, Person(), which is supposed to construct a new person with the given variables and store that information for reading later, and PeopleManager().

Person class:

```
public class Person extends Object 
{ 
private static int theNumPersons = 0; // initialize num 
private String itsFirstName; 
private String itsLastName; 
private int itsBirthYear; 

public Person (String first, String last, int year) 
{ 
    super(); 
    theNumPersons++; // update num 
    itsFirstName = first; 
    itsLastName = last; // initialize last name 
    itsBirthYear = year; 
}

/** Tell how many different Persons exist. */ 

public static int getNumPersons() // access num 
{ 
    return theNumPersons; 
} 

/** Return the birth year. */ 

public int getBirthYear() 
{ 
    return itsBirthYear; 
}

/** Return the first name. */ 

public String getFirstName() 
{ 
    return itsFirstName; 
}

/** Return the last name. */ 

public String getLastName() // access last name 
{ 
    return itsLastName; 
}

/** Replace the last name by the specified value. */ 

public void setLastName (String name) // update last name 
{ 
    itsLastName = name; 
}
}
```

PeopleManager class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PeopleManager
{
static ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
static int selection;

public static void main()
{
    askSelection();
}

public static void askSelection()
{
    Object[] options = { "Add to Database", "Retrieve Info" };
    selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What would you like to do?", "People Database Application", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    executeSelection();
}

public static void executeSelection()
{
    if (selection == 0)
    {
        addPerson();
        askSelection();
    }

    if (selection == 1)
    {
        Object[] nameArray = names.toArray();
        Object person = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select person to grab info from.", "People Database Application", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, nameArray, nameArray[0]);
        getInfo(person);
        askSelection();
    }
}

public static void addPerson()
{
        String newFirst = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the first name.", "John");
        String newLast = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter the last name.", "Doe");
        String sNewYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter that person's birth year.", "1965");
        String newFullName = (newFirst + " " + newLast);

        int iNewYear = Integer.parseInt(sNewYear);

        names.add(newFullName);
        Person newFullName = new Person (newFirst, newLast, iNewYear);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Person successfully added.");
    }

public static void getInfo(Object p)
{
    String infoFirst = p.getFirstName;
    String infoLast = p.getLastName;
    String infoYear = p.getBirthYear;
    String databaseSize = getNumPersons();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "First Name: " + infoFirst + "\nLast Name: " + infoLast + "\nBirth Year: " + infoYear + "\n\nTotal people in database: " + databaseSize);
}
}
```

I know I'm not doing something right, and I'm pretty sure it has to do with the way I tried to make a new Person() by using a variable.  The problem is, if I can't use a variable to make a new Person(), how can I give the stats to the application user that is specific to the person they entered in?

Comment: Why not return the instance of `Person` you create when calling `addPerson`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new.  What exactly do you mean?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Why is everything static in `PeopleManager`? I also think you might be petter off counting the people in the `PeopleManager` rather then having a static `theNumPersons`.

Comment: don't hesitate to ask questions. I had the same question some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Person object

```
    names.add(newFullName);
    Person newFullName = new Person (newFirst, newLast, iNewYear);
```

but you are not keeping that referenced (by adding it array or something) but you have names array that keep track of the names. Also, you should rename the variable to something else because you have 2 variable named the same.

EDIT:
As you asked, here is a simple example.

class1:

```
public class Person
{
    public String name;
    public String lastname; 

    public Person(String name, String lastname)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name + " " + this.lastname;
    }
}
```

class 2:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PersonManager{

    //array list to keep track of all the Person objects that will be created
    public static ArrayList<Person>peoples = new ArrayList<Person>();

    //assume this function takes input from user and returns a new 
    //person object
    public static Person getPerson(String name, String last)
    {
        Person p = new Person(name, last);
        return p;
    }

    //this function removes a person with the first name 
    public static boolean removePerson(String name)
    {
        //we should loop through the array and find the object we want to delete
        Person objectToRemove = null;
        for (Person p : peoples)
        {
            if (p.name.equals(name))    
            {
                //this is the object we want to remove
                //because the name matched
                objectToRemove = p;
                break;
            }
        }

        //we will actually remove the object outside of the loop
        //so we don't run into errors...
        if (objectToRemove != null)
        {
           //tell array list to remove the object we wanted to delete
           peoples.remove(objectToRemove);
          System.out.println("\nRemoving person = "+objectToRemove);

        }
        return objectToRemove != null;
    }   

    public static void printInfo()
    {

        System.out.println("\n\nPrinting info");
        //loop through all the object in the peoples array and print out their names
        for (Person p : peoples)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }

        System.out.println("In total, there are "+ peoples.size() +" objects saved in the array");

    }
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        //creating 3 different people and adding them to the array list
        peoples.add(getPerson("John", "Doe"));    
        peoples.add(getPerson("Jane", "Doe"));    
        peoples.add(getPerson("Will", "Smith"));  

        //print all the users in the array and the size of the array
        printInfo();

        //remove the person with first name = John.
        removePerson("John");

        //print all the users in the array and the size of the array
        printInfo();     
     }
}
```

Comment: If you have time, would you mind sharing a quick example of what you mean?  Thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
String newFullName = (newFirst + " " + newLast);
Person newFullName = new Person (newFirst, newLast, iNewYear);
```

you are saying newFullName is String and Person, this is impossible

also, you have to change the last function to this:

```
public static void getInfo(Person p)
{
    String infoFirst = p.getFirstName();
    String infoLast = p.getLastName();
    String infoYear = Integer.toString(p.getBirthYear());
    String databaseSize = Integer.toString(Person.getNumPersons());

    ...
}
```

Comment: See, the problem is that several different entities need to be created (but the amount of entities is up to the user) so that all of their individual data can be stored.  I thought that newFullName would work as a variable when constructing a new Person.  What other ways are there to do this?

Comment: In this case I would store the Persons in the ArrayList, not the strings of the name and last name. Implement toString() method in Person class too, to return desired string